# Update Error Query ("Empty Path Not Legal)

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]I'm a beginner in Programming and I'm making a C# Church Management System that saves member information. Everything works well except that I get an error "Empty path not legal" when I try to update records without updating the Member Image as well. I need your help

this is the codes for update button

```
 private void btnUpdate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] img = null;
            
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(ImgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
            

            // setting up connection string
            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = Localhost; Initial Catalog = ChurchProject; Integrated Security = True");
            con.Open();

            // using commands to get update member records when input
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update members set FullName=@name,Gender=@sex,DateOfBirth=@dob,Auxiliary=@aux,Location=@loc,Address=@address,Telephone=@tel,"
                + "WhatsApp=@whatsapp,Email=@email,[Membership Status]=@memberstat,[Marital Status]=@marital,[Baptismal Status]=@baptismStat,Occupation=@occup,[Baptismal Year]=@baptYear,"
                + "[Admission Year]=@admission,[Prev Church]=@prev,Prev_Position=@prevpost,MemberPic=@img where ID = @id", con);

            // assigning textboxes to database values
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dtpDOB.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aux", cmbAuxiliary.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", txtLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", txtTelNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whatsapp", txtWhatsApp.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberstat", cmbMembershipstat.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marital", cmbMarital.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baptismStat", cmbBaptism.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occup", txtOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baptYear", dtpBaptism.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission", dtpAdmission.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prev", txtPrevChurch.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prevpost", txtPosition.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));

            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Update the Records? This cannot be undone!", "Membership Update Status", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
            {


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Records Updated Successfully", "Membership Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                //Do nothing!
            }

          
            loadMemberRecords();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the ImgLoc property? How has it been implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason you have obtained this message is that the path passed to FileStream constructor is null or an empty string. Telepath in my head says that it seems that you have to pass all file operations if ImgLoc is null or an empty string like this:

```csharp
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ImgLoc))
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(ImgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
}
```

Also you have to update your SQL query text building like this:

```csharp
string sql = string.Format("update members set FullName=@name,Gender=@sex,DateOfBirth=@dob,Auxiliary=@aux,Location=@loc,Address=@address,Telephone=@tel,"
                + "WhatsApp=@whatsapp,Email=@email,[Membership Status]=@memberstat,[Marital Status]=@marital,[Baptismal Status]=@baptismStat,Occupation=@occup,[Baptismal Year]=@baptYear,"
                + "[Admission Year]=@admission,[Prev Church]=@prev,Prev_Position=@prevpost{0} where ID = @id", string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ImgLoc) ? "" : ", MemberPic=@img");

cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
```

And finally you have to ignore @img parameter in that case:

```csharp
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(ImgLoc))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
}
```